# iptables icmp Destination host unknown

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, routes, iptables

I am testing how to cause `java.net.NoRouteToHostException` using iptables. configure server side like this:

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.13.185.66 -j DROP`
`sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.13.185.66 -j REJECT`
`sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.13.185.66 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-net-unreachable`
when client side try to connect server side cause `java.net.ConnectException`: Connection refused instead of `java.net.NoRouteToHostException`, then i try to remove the route table result `java.io.IOException`, also not my expected.
How can i get a `java.net.NoRouteToHostException` ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Configure server iptables with only

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.13.185.66 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable
```

The first rule (`-j DROP`) causes the packets to be dropped, not rejected.

Comment: That's what i want.  I tried `icmp-net-unreachable` and some other options but miss `icmp-host-unreachable` option. Thanks for you advice